# Google Play Testing app crash - java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field Key of type Lkotlinx/coroutines/CoroutineExceptionHandler

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, proguard, google-play-console

The application works stably on tested emulators in the studio and real devices. When uploading to the Internal Testing section in Google Play, the device consistently crashes:

*Google Pixel 6
1080x2400
Android 12 (SDK 31)
8,192 MB
arm64-v8a.*

**Google Play Console stacktrace**

```
Exception java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field Key of type Lkotlinx/coroutines/CoroutineExceptionHandler$Key; in class Lkotlinx/coroutines/CoroutineExceptionHandler; or its superclasses (declaration of 'kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler' appears in /data/app/~~KWhmPpaU6JtpmIAZBH3isw==/androidx.test.tools.crawler-P3SH8J3nls-tHnM5nwslZg==/base.apk)
  at ua.at.tsvetkov.weather.ui.outfits.quick.QuickSelectionViewModel.<init> (QuickSelectionViewModel.kt:235)
  at ua.at.tsvetkov.weather.DaggerAppWeather_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get (DaggerAppWeather_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:644)
  at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory$2.createViewModel (HiltViewModelFactory.java:133)
  at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory$2.create (HiltViewModelFactory.java:104)
  at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create (HiltViewModelFactory.java:171)
  at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get (ViewModelProvider.kt:184)
  at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get (ViewModelProvider.kt:150)
  at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue (ViewModelLazy.kt:53)
  at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue (ViewModelLazy.kt:35)
  at ua.at.tsvetkov.weather.ui.outfits.quick.QuickSelectionFragment.getViewModel (QuickSelectionFragment.kt:55)
  at ua.at.tsvetkov.weather.ui.outfits.quick.QuickSelectionFragment.onCreateView (QuickSelectionFragment.kt:62)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:3114)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView (FragmentStateManager.java:557)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStateManager.java:272)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStore.java:114)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1455)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange (FragmentManager.java:3034)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated (FragmentManager.java:2945)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated (Fragment.java:3148)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView (FragmentStateManager.java:410)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStateManager.java:271)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView (FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:142)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView (FragmentController.java:136)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView (FragmentActivity.java:247)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView (FragmentActivity.java:226)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView (LayoutInflater.java:1073)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:1001)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:965)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:1127)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:1088)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude (LayoutInflater.java:1267)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:1123)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:1088)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude (LayoutInflater.java:1267)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:1123)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:1088)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:686)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:538)
  at ua.at.tsvetkov.weather.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate (ActivityMainBinding.java:53)
  at ua.at.tsvetkov.weather.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate (ActivityMainBinding.java:47)
  at ua.at.tsvetkov.weather.ui.main.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.kt:95)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8050)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8030)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1329)
  at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (MonitoringInstrumentation.java:2)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3608)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3792)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2210)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7839)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

All libraries were updated to the newest.
I tried both the empty **proguard-rules.pro** file and different options. This latest:

```
# Kotlinx
-keep interface kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler { *; }
-keep class kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidExceptionPreHandler
-keep class kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidDispatcherFactory

-keep class kotlinx.coroutines.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class kotlinx.coroutines.* {
    <fields>;
    <init>();
    <methods>;
}
-keep class dagger.hilt.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class dagger.hilt.* {
    <fields>;
    <init>();
    <methods>;
}

-dontwarn com.google.errorprone.annotations.**
-keepnames @dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel class * extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

-keep class kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatcherFactory { *; }
-keep class kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidExceptionPreHandler { *; }
-keep class kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler { *; }
-keep class kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidDispatcherFactory { *; }
-keep class kotlin.Result { *; }
-keepclassmembernames class kotlinx.** {
    volatile <fields>;
}
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```
@file:Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")

import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.util.Properties

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("kotlin-android")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
    id("androidx.room") version "2.6.1"
}

val skipCommitsCount = 0 // add to verCode if need to align commits count
val verCode = providers.exec {
    commandLine("git", "rev-list", "--count", "HEAD")
}.standardOutput.asText.get().trim().toInt()
val gitSha = providers.exec {
    commandLine("git", "rev-parse", "--short", "HEAD")
}.standardOutput.asText.get().trim()

val verMajor = 1
val verMinor = 0
val verPatch = 0
val verName = "${verMajor}.${verMinor}.${verPatch}.${verCode}"

val getWeatherApiKey = {
    val properties = Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file("local.properties").reader())
    properties.getProperty("weather_api_key", "")
}

fun getLocalProperty(key: String, file: String = "local.properties"): Any {
    val properties = Properties()
    val localProperties = File(file)
    if (localProperties.isFile) {
        InputStreamReader(FileInputStream(localProperties), Charsets.UTF_8).use { reader ->
            properties.load(reader)
        }
    } else error("File from not found")

    return properties.getProperty(key)
}

android {
    namespace = "ua.at.tsvetkov.weather"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "ua.at.tsvetkov.weather"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = verCode
        versionName = verName
        buildConfigField("String", "GIT_SHA", "\"${gitSha}\"")
        buildConfigField("String", "WEATHER_API_KEY", "\"${getLocalProperty("weather_api_key")}\"")
        buildConfigField("String", "WEATHER_API_HOST", "\"https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/\"")
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                argument("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas")
            }
        }
        kapt {
            arguments {
                arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas")
            }
        }
        resourceConfigurations.addAll(listOf("en", "ru", "uk"))
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            isDebuggable = false
            isShrinkResources = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        dataBinding = true
        buildConfig = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.2.0"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            pickFirsts += "META-INF/LICENSE"
            pickFirsts += "META-INF/INDEX.LIST"
            pickFirsts += "META-INF/DEPENDENCIES"
            pickFirsts += "META-INF/*.properties"
            pickFirsts += "META-INF/AL2.0"
            pickFirsts += "META-INF/LGPL2.1"
            pickFirsts += "git.properties"
        }
    }
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true // Allow references to generated code
}

room {
    schemaDirectory(path = "$projectDir/schemas")
}

hilt {
    enableAggregatingTask = true
}

dependencies {

    implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar", "*.aar"))))
    implementation(files("libs/tao-core-1.5.0.aar"))
    implementation(files("libs/tao-log-2.1.0.aar"))

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.5.0")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.6.2")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.5.1")

    val navVersion = "2.7.7"
    val liveVersion = "2.7.0"
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.8.2")
    implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$liveVersion")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$liveVersion")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$liveVersion")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx:$liveVersion")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navVersion")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navVersion")
    implementation("androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1")
    implementation("androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.1")
    implementation("androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:8.2.2")
    implementation("androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0")
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2")
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.2.0")

    // Google
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:21.0.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.1.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.play:app-update-ktx:2.1.0")
//    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.6.0")

    // Firebase
    val firebaseVersion = "8.0.2"
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.2"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.5.1")
    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
    implementation("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:$firebaseVersion")
    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Fire store
    implementation("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:$firebaseVersion")
    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
    implementation("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:$firebaseVersion")
    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Storage
    implementation("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:$firebaseVersion")

    //Hilt
    val hiltVersion ="1.2.0"
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.50")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.50")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:$hiltVersion")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-work:$hiltVersion")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-common:$hiltVersion")
    kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:$hiltVersion")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.8.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.8.0")

    val workVersion = "2.9.0"
    implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$workVersion")
    implementation("androidx.work:work-gcm:$workVersion")

    //Retrofit
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")

    // Room
    val roomVersion = "2.6.1"
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
    // Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")

    // Data
    implementation("de.siegmar:fastcsv:2.2.2") 
    implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0")

    // Glide
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0")
    ksp("com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.16.0")

    // Lottie
    val lottieVersion = "6.3.0"
    implementation("com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion")

    // Circle ImageView
    implementation("com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:4.3.1")

    //ml-kit selfie segmentation
    implementation("com.google.mlkit:segmentation-selfie:16.0.0-beta4")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-subject-segmentation:16.0.0-beta1")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.3.0")

    val cameraxVersion = "1.3.1"
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-core:${cameraxVersion}")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${cameraxVersion}")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${cameraxVersion}")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-video:${cameraxVersion}")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-view:${cameraxVersion}")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-extensions:${cameraxVersion}")

    // Blur
    implementation("jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:4.3.0")
    implementation("jp.wasabeef:blurry:4.0.1")

    // LeakCanary
//    debugImplementation ("com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:3.0-alpha-1")

    // Testing
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

03.14.24 Upd. The error appeared again without any changes on my part.

Comment: Started happening for me after I added an unrelated 3rd party SDK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been fixed by the Firebase team. Prelaunch report should run fine now. See the chat thread here : https://firebase-community.slack.com/archives/C1MTSQ5QT/p1708536667082259

Comment: I got again this the same crash in Google Play Console:
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field Key of type Lkotlinx/coroutines/CoroutineExceptionHandler$Key; in class Lkotlinx/coroutines/CoroutineExceptionHandler; or its superclasses (declaration of 'kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler' appears in /data/app/~~ZZfFNpyv5dxNKERkwpVMRg==/androidx.test.tools.crawler-FmCGuQPrqbx_DEuFwdssnQ==/base.apk)

Comment: Same here, it started yesterday. I either get the same crash as @LordTAO or another one like `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method H(LR6/j;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V in class Lkotlinx/coroutines/CoroutineExceptionHandler` depending on what coroutines items I put in Proguard. There was no issue before yesterday, and none of my dependencies have changed.

Comment: More discussion here: https://firebase-community.slack.com/archives/C1MTSQ5QT/p1710337036436009

Comment: I can't enter in to the workspace, because "....gmail.com doesn’t have an account on this workspace"

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved.

I'm not sure which answer is correct. I actually found two versions of coroutine libraries. I have 1.8.0 installed, but there is also version 1.5.0. Most likely there is an internal dependency somewhere.
I made corrections - added forcing the required version in the root gradle file.

Now I can’t say which decision is correct since it coincided with a fix from the Firebase team. In any case, I am adding this possible solution.

**build.gradle.kts**

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1")
        classpath("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9")
    }
}

plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.22" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.48.1" apply false
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.0" apply false
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin") version "2.7.5" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.22-1.0.16" apply false
}

val coroutinesVersion = "1.8.0" // check version in app gradle file!

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesVersion")
        force("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:$coroutinesVersion")
        force("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutinesVersion")
        force("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$coroutinesVersion")
    }
}
```