# Crash report in the Google Play Console java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field Key of type Lkotlinx/coroutines/CoroutineExceptionHandler$Key;

Tags: prelaunch

I recently received a crash report in the Google Play Console. Several previous builds were successful without any failures. And I noticed that a few builds ago the same issue was happened once but next build was successful. I have not updated libraries or ProGuard rules since the successful build to the current one.

```
Exception java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field Key of type Lkotlinx/coroutines/CoroutineExceptionHandler$Key; in class Lkotlinx/coroutines/CoroutineExceptionHandler; or its superclasses (declaration of 'kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler' appears in /data/app/~~bRczeIULLF7OCHbFjrQ9Mw==/androidx.test.tools.crawler-7xI20jIX-AV6_dSZ79kK0g==/base.apk)
  at androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontListFontFamilyTypefaceAdapter.<clinit> (FontListFontFamilyTypefaceAdapter.kt:474)
  at androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamilyResolverImpl.<init> (FontFamilyResolver.kt:31)
  at androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamilyResolver_androidKt.createFontFamilyResolver (FontFamilyResolver.android.kt:40)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.<init> (AndroidComposeView.android.kt:449)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.Wrapper_androidKt.setContent (Wrapper.android.kt:77)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.ensureCompositionCreated (ComposeView.android.kt:251)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onAttachedToWindow (ComposeView.android.kt:283)
  at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow (View.java:20753)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3490)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3497)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3497)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3497)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2630)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:2143)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:8665)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1037)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:845)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:780)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:1022)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7839)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

The report says that it happened on the google Pixel 6 Android 12 (SDK 31)

[It looks like the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78041019/google-play-testing-app-crash-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-no-field-key-of-type) but with different stack trace.

What could be the reason for the crash?

Comment: Receiving the same error. Have updated all compose, kotlin libraries etc to the latest. I also sent an inquiry to Firebase support as they maintain the crawler doing the testing for pre-launch reports. No luck.

Comment: Seems related: https://firebase-community.slack.com/archives/C1MTSQ5QT/p1710337036436009